# Inflated listview item don't appear as pressed

Tags: android, button, view

Sorry if this is too trivial or if it had been previously posted. Right now, I'm with this issue. I have a ListView component where I'm creating a set of items, each one being inflated layouts. When I click in one item, the behavior **onClick** is full functional and the listeners are doing their job, but the ListView don't show the "pressed status" in the buttons. The below image shows what I'm seeking for:

[image]

Does anyone have a hint to give me? I already checked and tryed a couple of things:
 1. android:state_focused="true"
 2. android:state_pressed="true"
 3. setClickable(true)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually apply styles to the states of the list item. Because, you are creating your own list item view instead of android list item view. so, you have to provide specific styles to show the different states.
Use selector to make the style to the list item. some sample code i am provided here,

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_gradient" />

    <!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_focus" />

</selector>
```

And in the listview

`<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_background" />`